# Lambda function is failing to assume role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sts, assume-role

I am working on a scenario where I would like to authorize lambda function based on cognito user pool's group role.

**I have created a role for the user group:**

Role Name: AppAdmin

AWS managed Permission policies:

- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonCognitoPowerUser

Trust relationship:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:assumed-role/lambdaRole/LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME",
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And, I have created another role for the lambda function:**

Role Name: lambdaRole

Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionToAssumeAppAdmin",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:role/AppAdmin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that all these are in same AWS account.

Now, if I try to assume AppAdmin role from lambda:

```
const AWS= require('aws-sdk');
let sts = new AWS.STS();


exports.main = async function(event) {
    console.log('event: '+ JSON.stringify(event));
    const msg= event.requestContext.authorizer.claims['cognito:roles'];

    let response= {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'Some error occurred on the server.',
        }),
    }
    await sts.assumeRole({
        RoleArn: JSON.stringify(msg),
        RoleSessionName: 'Cognito_Cognito_DefaultRole',
    }).promise().then(data => {
        console.log('Assumed role success :)');
        console.log('Data is: '+data);
        let creds = new AWS.Credentials({
            accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
            secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
            sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Cannot assume role :(');
        console.log(err, err.stack);
      })
};
```

I am getting below error:

```
2022-02-18T13:46:45.204Z    fdd8c0d2-442d-4324-ba93-673cb4e5f327    INFO    AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:assumed-role/lambdaRole/LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:role/AppAdmin"
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'AccessDenied',
  time: 2022-02-18T13:46:45.162Z,
  requestId: 'feabf3ff-c4b6-45c5-8606-4c1c59b9af10',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 59.233565937215026
} AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:assumed-role/lambdaRole/LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:role/AppAdmin"
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!!!

Comment: I also tried to check this with IAM Policy Simulator, and it tells that Role "lambdaRole" can call AssumeRole action of service "AWS Security Token Service" on resource arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_NUMBER:role/AppAdmin sucessfully. Not sure why it is a problem for Lambda

Comment: Does the trust policy on the AppAdmin role allow the lambdaRole ARN to assume it? Also, don't use both `await` and `.then()` on the same promise.